# Using an active GPS antenna in the SIM868 module

Tags: antenna, gnss, simcom

Is it better to connect to VBAT or to VDD_EXT in the SIM868 module to supply the active GPS antenna voltage?

Comment: What antenna? To what SIM868 module? And link to the datasheets please.

Comment: https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM868/SIM868_RF_Design_Application%20Note_V1.00.pdf

For active GPS antenna

Answer (score 0):

sim868 equipped with internal lna for gps , then using active antenna isn't necessary.
These series include gnss complete engine (a-gps + 3 different satellite system ) , an advanced mixed location tracking algorithm so combination of these hardware and software futures increased antenna sensitivity for cold start in order better 5han -166dbm ,

However if your antenna is an active type then you must do DC biasing for antenna lna .

In simcom documents ( sim 868 hardware design manual ) you can find reference circuit schematic and detailed description about GPS active antenna.

Summery of that saying you must add a low pass RL filter for biasing active antenna , inductor range is 27nh to 56nh series with 10R resistor ( this resistor used for current limiting in short circuit of antenna )

Low pass filter must connect to dc source voltage 2.8 to 3.0 volt and current drown by external lna is in order 3 to 5 ma .

We usually connect this biasing filter to one of gpios of sim800 series, you can turn external biasing circuit on and off by configuring that gpio as output with level 0 or 1 via at commands, by this type of connection you save one pin of system and it is selectable power supply for active antenna, whenever gps is not in use you can disable antenna power supply and save battery charge .